# Transfer gamesaves from Xbox 360 to Xbox One?

Tags: xbox-360, borderlands-2, xbox-one

I have the GOTY edition of Borderlands 2 on my Xbox One X. My question is can I use my gamesaves from my Xbox 360 which is the regular version (not GOTY). I don't want to upload to the cloud and screw up my Xbox One save. thanks for any information on this